# Search log for regex pattern, then search surrounding lines again for previous match

Tags: awk, sed

I have a log that contains lines from processes that handle authentications. Such an authentication usually consists of 4 lines. For example:

```
2022-09-21T00:02:45 [18633]: connection opened
2022-09-21T00:02:45 [3711]: connection opened
2022-09-21T00:02:45 [61811]: connection opened
2022-09-21T00:02:45 [9957]: connection opened
2022-09-21T00:02:46 [3711]: authentication attempt
2022-09-21T00:02:46 [61811]: authentication attempt
2022-09-21T00:02:49 [3711]: user FOO authentication failure
2022-09-21T00:02:51 [18633]: authentication attempt
2022-09-21T00:02:51 [9957]: authentication attempt
2022-09-21T00:03:01 [9957]: user QOZ authentication failure
2022-09-21T00:03:02 [3711]: connection closed
2022-09-21T00:03:34 [61811]: user BAR authentication success
2022-09-21T00:03:38 [61811]: connection closed
2022-09-21T00:03:45 [18633]: user BAZ authentication success
2022-09-21T00:03:45 [18633]: connection closed
2022-09-21T00:04:11 [9957]: connection closed
```

I would like to find all the logs that deal with a successful authentication.
I can do this by finding the PIDs of those, and then grepping the file again for all lines that contain that PID:

```bash
for pid in $(cat log.txt | sed -En 's/.*\[([0-9]+)\].*success/\1/p'); do
  grep $pid log.txt
done
```

This works:

```
2022-09-21T00:02:45 [61811]: connection opened
2022-09-21T00:02:46 [61811]: authentication attempt
2022-09-21T00:03:34 [61811]: user BAR authentication success
2022-09-21T00:03:38 [61811]: connection closed
2022-09-21T00:02:45 [18633]: connection opened
2022-09-21T00:02:51 [18633]: authentication attempt
2022-09-21T00:03:45 [18633]: user BAZ authentication success
2022-09-21T00:03:45 [18633]: connection closed
```

But it is very inefficient as there are many events, and I'm grepping the entire file for all of them. On a multi GB file this is undoable.

I'm looking for an alternative way to do this. Is there a way to (perhaps in `awk`?) to do something like this?

1. Match lines with `authentication success` and extract the PID
2. Search in the neighbourhood (say 10 lines before and after the match) for lines with that PID, and return all of them

many thx

Comment: This will read the file twice, but should be faster than your attempt: `grep -Ff <(awk -F'[][]' '/success/{print "[" $2 "]"}' log.txt) log.txt` (and this can be further sped up by using `ripgrep`) .. pipe the output to `sort -t'[' -k2,2n` if you want the PIDs bunched together

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```bash
awk -F'[][]' '/success/{a[$2]; for(k in p) if(p[k]==$2) print h[k]}
              $2 in a{print}
              {i=NR%13; p[i]=$2; h[i]=$0}' log.txt
```

- `-F'[][]'` use `[` and `]` as field separators, so that `$2` gives the PID
- `{i=NR%13; p[i]=$2; h[i]=$0}` this saves PID in array `p` and corresponding line in `h` (number `13` determines how many previous lines are saved)
- `/success/{a[$2]; for(k in p) if(p[k]==$2) print h[k]}` when a new success PID is found, save that PID in array `a` and print matching results based on previously saved data in array `p` and `h`
- `$2 in a{print}` this will print lines having successful PID from current line onwards

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking look at [Context Line Control of `grep`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), more precisely using `--context=NUM` option for preprocessing, which should allows you to extract interesting subset of your text file, thus providing smaller easier to process file.

Consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
Able
Baker
Charlie
Charlie
Dog
Easy
Fox
```

then

```
grep --context=1 'Charlie' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Baker
Charlie
Charlie
Dog
```

As you can see 1 line before and after is included.

*(tested in GNU grep 3.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this instead:

```
$ sort -k2,2 -k1,1 file |
    awk '
        $2 != prev { if (rec ~ /success/) print rec; rec=""; prev=$2 }
        { rec = rec $0 ORS }
        END { if (rec ~ /success/) print rec }
    '
2022-09-21T00:02:45 [18633]: connection opened
2022-09-21T00:02:51 [18633]: authentication attempt
2022-09-21T00:03:45 [18633]: connection closed
2022-09-21T00:03:45 [18633]: user BAZ authentication success

2022-09-21T00:02:45 [61811]: connection opened
2022-09-21T00:02:46 [61811]: authentication attempt
2022-09-21T00:03:34 [61811]: user BAR authentication success
2022-09-21T00:03:38 [61811]: connection closed
```

or if you wanted the output ordered by the success line's timestamp rather than the PID you could do:

```
sort -k2,2 -k1,1 file |
    awk -v OFS='\t' '
        $2 != prev { prt(); numLines=0; time=""; prev=$2 }
        /success/ { time = $1 }
        { rec[++numLines] = $0 }
        END { prt() }
        function prt(    i) {
            if (time) {
                for (i=1; i<=numLines; i++) {
                    print time, prev, rec[i]
                }
            }
        }
    ' |
    sort -k1,1 -k2,2 |
    cut -f2-
2022-09-21T00:02:45 [61811]: connection opened
2022-09-21T00:02:46 [61811]: authentication attempt
2022-09-21T00:03:34 [61811]: user BAR authentication success
2022-09-21T00:03:38 [61811]: connection closed
2022-09-21T00:02:45 [18633]: connection opened
2022-09-21T00:02:51 [18633]: authentication attempt
2022-09-21T00:03:45 [18633]: connection closed
2022-09-21T00:03:45 [18633]: user BAZ authentication success
```